# GDAL Python zonal statistics

Tags: python, gdal

I have a result of multiple rasters being put together I'm trying to do zonal statistics on that final result, but no matter what I search for all I find is related to polygons with rasters, unless I'm missing something here, I truly might not understand this subject really well but no matter what I search I find nothing explained briefly on why I need polygons in it when I'm working on a raster
Also what I'm trying to do is a change from this:[image]

To this using zonal statistics:
[image]

The code I'm currently using:

```
cl_string = "-tr 150 150 -r average"
warp_options = gdal.WarpOptions(gdal.ParseCommandLine(cl_string))
gdal.Warp(destNameOrDestDS="final_raster_Grided.tiff",srcDSOrSrcDSTab="final_raster.tiff", options=warp_options)
```

which results in the following image:[image]

Comment: I dont understand. What do you want to use to define the areas if not polygons? Another raster?

Comment: @BERA I may not understand the concept at all, but here is what I want to do, I have a raster.tiff which is a result of 5 layers being combined, I want to apply zonal statistics on that final layer but how can I do that when I don't have a polygon to define the zone

Comment: What are the statistics you want to calculate?

Comment: @BERA I want to get the 2nd picture as a result of scaling each grid in the raster, like in the first picture I have the raster that I want to apply average grid cutting on to get the second picture as a result

Comment: Create a polygon [grid](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgiscreategrid), then use it as zones

Comment: @BERA I created a grid polygon but and I found a way to use it as zones and get the result as a dict of mean values, but I can't seem to have a way of converting it into an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are effectively trying to do is downsample the first image using an average value. There are multiple ways of doing this:

Zonal statistics: for this you need a raster and a vector. The vector should be a grid at the resolution you want each 'square' to be in figure 2. You can make one of these in qgis or arcmap. It's is known as a regular grid or a fishnet. You can then extract the average zonal stat and rasterize it to get an image

Resampling: This may be a little more difficult to define, but you can just resample the image to a coarser resolution using gdalwarp.

To be clear, zonal statistics usually uses a vector and a raster where the vector defines the area over which you want to perform the extraction (min, mean, max etc). You can do raster to raster but this is usually known as image zone and not zonal statistics

In QGIS3 go to processing > toolbox and search for "zonal". You should see a Zone statistics tool you can use

Comment: I searched and tried a lot of raster functions but couldn't find anything that could help me do it, I created the vector polygon grid but couldn't find a way to implement the zonal statistics function

Comment: @Al-MeqdadJabi In QGIS3 got to processing > toolbox and then search for zonal statistics. There is a "Zonal statistics" tool

Comment: Thank you so much just saw the function and I used it to apply zonal statistics, still didn't get what I wanted but it's the closet to it.